# Can't type SPC in second prompt on rgrep

Tags: rgrep

Linux Mint 20, Emacs 27.2

I want to find text "end" in the org files AND java files in my folder (recursively). So I use **rgrep**

```
M-x rgrep
```

Step1
[image]

Step2
[image]

But when I try to input `*.org SPC *.java`, I can't type `SPC`.  I get message `"No match"`

I know that I can use `C-q SPC` but I want type `SPC` only by type `SPC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> tells us:

```
SPC runs the command minibuffer-complete-word (found in
minibuffer-local-completion-map), which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in ‘minibuffer.el’.

Complete the minibuffer contents at most a single word.
After one word is completed as much as possible, a space or hyphen
is added, provided that matches some possible completion.
Return nil if there is no valid completion, else t.
```

Which firmly suggests that changing this particular binding is
going to affect more than just `rgrep` prompts.  Still, you can do this as follows if you wish to:

```el
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
```

You've already mentioned one workaround with <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd>
but there's another one which is almost as easy to type as <kbd>SPC</kbd>
itself:

<kbd>M-SPC</kbd> runs `cycle-spacing` which, in the absence of any
space at point, inserts a single space.  YMMV, but this binding is sufficiently convenient for me to not care when
<kbd>SPC</kbd> has a non-space binding.